how to make one line splited to multiply lines
I want to make it look like this
def main(msg):
    if msg.chat.type == 'private':
        if msg.text == lang.suggest_song:

            msg = bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, "<b><a href = 'https://soundc10ud.com'>•Soundc10ud</a></b>", parse_mode= • html', reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, link)

instead of this
def main(msg):
    if msg.chat.type == 'private':
        if msg.text == lang.suggest_song:

            msg = bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, "<b><a href = 'https://soundc10ud.com'>•Soundc10ud</a></b>",
            parse_mode= • html', reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
            
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, link)

ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ
ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ
Maybe anyone know how to do thisㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ
This doesn't must join multiply lines to one, it must only work like one line

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

set a maximum line length in your code formatter

I edited the question, because of Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?

How do I turn on word wrap?
You can control word wrap through the editor.wordWrap setting. By default, editor.wordWrap is off but if you set to it to on, text will wrap on the editor's viewport width.
"editor.wordWrap": "on"

You can toggle word wrap for the VS Code session with Alt+Z.
Copied text from:
Basic Editing in Visual Studio Code

its not about word wrap but using a code formatter
